# azure time series insights materialized view

Tags: azure, time, series

I'm currently storing IoT data in Time Stream Insights. I'm looking for recommendations as to how to approach creating a materialized view consisting of certain attributes of each event that I can write out to other blobs. Say I have a message with x,y and z attributes keyed by a session identifier. I would like to append all x attributes to a blob named after that session id so the resulting blob would only contain every value of attribute x for the given session id. I understand how to write to blobs etc. What I'm looking for is how to tie that into the Time Series Insights so that I can perform that action every time a new event is ingested.

Comment: Have you considered making some data processing on the data sources that feed into TSI? E.g. you could have a separate consumer group on an Event Hub that you can use to listen to the same events that go to TSI.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I had considered that also but was looking to see what creative solutions people have applied. It looks like that may be the way to go though.